# Why selenium can not open some asp page?

Tags: asp.net, python, selenium-rc

I use selenium-rc to test an asp.net website, test script is written in Python and the browser is Firefox 3.6. But When selenium open the first page of the website, A download dialog appear, not the web page, seems the page is proccessed as application/octet-stream, this cause my test script can not run successfully.

Seems this behavior happened on some asp.net websites, I select other asp sites to test, and found some asp sites have the same issue.

My question is why this happend? and how to fix this?

Edit: I use IE to do this test again, seems it's ok. So is this an issue of Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I upgrade my selenium-server to 2.0b2, now it's ok.